# How to free memory using Java Unsafe, using a Java reference?

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, directmemory

Java Unsafe class allows you to allocate memory for an object as follows, but using this method how would you free up the memory allocated when finished, as it does not provide the memory address...

```
    Field f = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe"); //Internal reference
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) f.get(null);

    //This creates an instance of player class without any initialization
    Player p = (Player) unsafe.allocateInstance(Player.class);
```

Is there a way of accessing the memory address from the object reference, maybe the integer returned by the default hashCode implementation will work, so you could do...

```
 unsafe.freeMemory(p.hashCode());
```

doesn't seem right some how...

Comment: To free memory "held" by a Java reference you null the reference.

Comment: Theoretically, yes, because Unsafe allows you to do anything the JVM can do (by manipulating the JVM's memory). Doing so would require intricate knowledge of the internal implementation details of the JVM. (In other words: no, you can't.)

Comment: The question probably arises from an idea that `Unsafe.allocateInstance` might allocate objects out of Java Heap. But this is not true. `allocateInstance` works exactly like `new Object()` except that it does not call constructor.

Answer (score 13):

- "Memory address" of an object reference does not make sense since objects can move across Java Heap.
- You cannot explicitly free space allocated by `Unsafe.allocateInstance`, because this space belongs to Java Heap, and only Garbage Collector can free it.
- If you want your own memory management outside Java Heap, you may use `Unsafe.allocateMemory` / `Unsafe.freeMemory` methods. They deal with raw memory addresses represented as `long`. However this memory is not for Java objects.